# Run a script (for an app GUI) when logged from NX but limit shell commands on terminal

Tags: ssh, account-restrictions, authorization, nx

I have a user which will be accessing an app GUI via NX NoMachine. I want to allow this user to execute the command to bring up the app GUI (done automatically by NX) BUT prevent him from executing any other commands from Putty.

I've been trying to achieve this using .bash_profile and .bashrc but I've had no luck.

How can I do this this?